# Insert null value in an association table

Tags: sql

I have a problem with something in SQL, let's see an example of database :

```
CREATE TABLE person( //Employee
     pe_id PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     pe_name VARCHAR(20),
     pe_office VARCHAR(20)
); 

CREATE TABLE project( //Mission
     pr_id PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     pr_name VARCHAR(20),
     pr_status VARCHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE techno( //Programming language
     te_id PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     te_name VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE job( //developer, manager, ...
     jo_id PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     jo_name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

I would like to assign persons on projects for a job using technos.
For example, Rob works as a developer and project manager on the projet #13 with AngularJS and HTML.

So I created this table :

```
CREATE TABLE assignment(
    pe_id INT,
    pr_id INT,
    te_id INT,
    jo_id INT,
    as_days INT, //Days of work
    PRIMARY KEY(pe_id, pr_id, tr_id, jo_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_as_pe_id FOREIGN KEY(pe_id) REFERENCES person(pe_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_as_pr_id FOREIGN KEY(pr_id) REFERENCES project(pr_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_as_te_id FOREIGN KEY(te_id) REFERENCES techno(te_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_as_jo_id FOREIGN KEY(jo_id) REFERENCES job(jo_id)
);
```

I would like to have the ability to assign a developer with somes technos to a project without knowing who exaclty, like this:

`INSERT INTO assignment(pr_id,te_id,jo_id,as_days) VALUES(1,2,3,4); //No person!`

We suppose that this values exists in project, techno and job tables.

But it seems that I can not insert this, probably because I do not define person's ID (which is in the primary key).

How can I do this ?

Hope I'm understandable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solve this problem by not having this as a primary key. Primary keys cannot be NULL or, if they're composite primary keys, cannot contain NULL. *Make it a unique index instead*. Create an autonumber field for the primary key. I think this is better solution in your case

- Primary Key:

Can be only one in a table

It never allows null values

Primary Key is unique key identifier and can not be null and must be unique.

- Unique Key:

Can be more than one unique key in one table.

Unique key can have null values(only single null is allowed).

It can be a candidate key

Unique key can be null and may not be unique.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the answer you prupose ? It seems interesting. Thanks

Comment: it means you should change your primary to unique key

Comment: It does not seems to be a good solution, because if I remove pe_id from my primary key, it will become `PRIMARY KEY(pr_id, tr_id, jo_id)`, and it is not what I want :/

Comment: You change your primary key to unique key and get possibility to add _NULL_ for this column what do you want to do. Why do you use composite primary in this case, it means that one developer cant do the same work twice, better use many to many relationship

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do this:

Before insert disable constraint:

```
ALTER INDEX fk_as_pe_id ON assignment
DISABLE;
```

After insert enable it:

```
ALTER INDEX fk_as_pe_id ON assignment
REBUILD;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate way is, if it is possible to alter table structure, just exclude pe_id from the composite primary key in assignment table